# Regex match a specific char and don't match another one

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a file like this one, I want to match some of the strings:

```
https://site.me/ //matches
https://site.me// //does not match (there is a slash)
https://site.me/deck //does not match (there is not a dot)
https://site.me/hello.php //matches (there is a dot and zero slashes)
https://site.me/deck/hello.php //does not match (there is a slash)
```

The pattern should be: `https://site.me/` followed by any slash does not match. Followed by a dot and not a slash matches. Followed by any chars with no dots does not match.

Here is [my try](http://regexr.com/3ci2n):

```
https://site.me/((?!/).)*$
```

Comment: Please precise the language/tool. It matters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're over-complicating it.

This suits the requirement you described :

```
 ^https://site.me/([^/.]*\.[^/.]*)?$
```

But the *real* requirement (not the one you wrote) is probably more complex. It's probable for example you don't want spaces, and you don't want just a dot. Here's a probably better solution

```
 ^https://site.me/([^/.\s]+\.[^/.\s]+)?$
```

Comment: Sure, not only, I even *tried* (did you?) the regexps in the online tester, otherwise I would not comment. And `^https://site.me/[^/.\s]+\.[^/.\s]+$` will not allow `https://site.me/`.

Comment: @stribizhev You're right about that second point. Fixed. But I still don't understand your point about *"https://site.me/."*. OP didn't tell he doesn't want it. I just assumed it (second part of my answer).

Comment: Yes, just instead of *This suits your requirement* I'd say *This regex matches the example input strings*, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply match for any optional filename after the url:

```
^https://site\.me/([^/]+\.[^/]+)?$
```

- `[^/]+` match anything but a `/` one or more time (call it `X`)
- `[^/]+\.[^/]+` match `X.X`
- `?` make the whole filename part optional

[Try it out live here](https://regex101.com/r/mU3qX1/1)

Comment: *`[^/]+\.[^/]+` match "anything.anything"* - in fact, it matches 1 or more symbols other than `/`, then a literal period and again 1 or more symbols other than `/`. Not just anything.

Comment: Though that was clear with only the first descritption of `[^/]+`, will edit a bit.

Comment: I just meant to say that anything implies an empty string, while `+` makes the previous pattern to appear at least 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^https://site\.me/([^/.]+\.[^/]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ8tZ9/2)

`([^/.]+\.[^/]+)?` makes part after `https://site.me/` optional. However if it is entered then there must be a DOT in it.

Comment: Just a notice: you escaped the /. From the regex in the question it doesn't look like that's required.

Comment: I agree, in the demo I didn't escape `/` but wasn't sure what language OP is using so escaped it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here it worked for me

```
/^https://site\.me/([^\/]+.*?\.php)?$/
```